# How to use different fonts in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4-beta

I'm a newbie.  I know I can assign different fonts for Bootstrap 4 like this default,

```
font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
```

What I want to know if I try to build a website with two font pairing for example,

```
font-family: "Roboto", "Open Sans";
```

How would the above code affect elements of Bootstrap 4. Which elements will get Roboto or Open Sans.

Comment: Depends what class or is you assign that new font family to. Are you assigning it to h1? p? *? What does the lines before font-family look like?

Comment: @Jack I think you mean I have to assign them as needed for each element of Bootstrap else they all default to Roboto for the example above?

Comment: See the answers below. They clear up what I mean by this.

Comment: Why can't this be answered w/o referring to "Roboto"? Is it even possible to use a font other than Roboto? What if I naively inquired about using 3 fonts w/o any of them being Roboto? Forgive me if that's an absurd question. Seems Roboto is bootstrapped into bootstrap! Roboto.

Answer (score 19):

For `scss` users:

Say you picked google fonts from here (pick less to load page fast):
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto

And, placed it in your `index.html` in `<head>`:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or, placed it in your stylesheet:

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400');
</style>
```

and in scss do this:

```
$font-family-base: 'Roboto', sans-serif; // add this line first before importing bootstrap
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

that's it.

Comment: So in order to replace Roboto you're saying use Roboto and put that in the HEAD of my HTML and that will allow me to use "Open Sans"?

Comment: @infin80 you got it wrong, if you like to use Roboto or any other font then use any one method that I have defined above (either import font link in head or in your stylesheet)

Answer (score 2):

You can override the bootstrap classes with your own css rules.

For example:

```
p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be assigned in whatever element you are trying to style, so for example:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
font-family: "Roboto";
}
```

This would assign Roboto to all the Headings...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use bootstraps sass variables to change the default font-family.
This is what default value is
`$font-family-sans-serif: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";`

`$font-family-sans-serif: Roboto;`

You can change it to whatever you want and build it using sass compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want the base font to be "Open Sans" and all headings to be "Roboto". If you're using `scss` you will only have to change these two variables;

```
$font-family-base:            'Open Sans', sans-serif;
$headings-font-family:        'Roboto', sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can also specify for which paragraphs should each font be applied:

```
<p class="sentenceA">First Paragraph with Roboto font applied to it.</p>
<p class="sentenceB">Second Paragraph with Open Sans font applied to it.</p>
<p class="sentenceC">Third Paragraph with Roboto and Open Sans fonts applied to it.</p>

//and in your stylesheet have something like:    

    .sentenceA p
    {
        font-family: "Roboto";
    }

    .sentenceB p
    {
      font-family: "Open Sans";
    }        

    .sentenceC p
    {
       font-family: "Roboto", "Open Sans";
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -4):

Since BootStrap4 uses jQuery to view most of it's features upon page load, it is not possible to change font-family by a simple **css**. We can use simple **jQuery** code to achieve this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div").css("font-family",'"Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif');
})
```

The above snippet will change regular font-family to 'Comic Sans MS' format.